# Dimension of free module tensor residue field

Tags: commutative-algebra, tensor-products

Let $A$ be a ring, and $\mathfrak{m}$ be a maximal ideal in $A$. Then why does $(A/\mathfrak{m}) \otimes_A A^n$ have dimension $n$ as a vector space over $A/\mathfrak{m}$?  I can show that the elements $\bar{1} \otimes e_i$ generate this vector space, where $e_i$'s are the generators of $A^n$, but how do I show their linear independence?

Comment: Are you aware of the fact that $(A/\mathfrak{m}) \otimes_A A = A/\mathfrak{m}$ and  $(M \oplus M) \otimes A = (M\otimes A) \oplus (M\otimes A)$?

Comment: Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 2):

As Parthiv commented:

$A/\mathfrak{m} \otimes_A A^n 
= A/\mathfrak{m} \otimes_A (\oplus_{i=1}^nA) 
\simeq \oplus_{i=1}^n (A/\mathfrak{m} \otimes_A A)
\simeq \oplus_{i=1}^n A/\mathfrak{m}
= (A/\mathfrak{m})^n$.

Comment: Very minor point (for people like me who get hung up on these kinds of things): the isomorphism you've written down is an isomorphism of $A$-modules. You also have to check that it's an isomorphism of $A/\mathfrak{m}$-modules, which it is (and it's not hard to check).

Comment: I think it's a good point.  I forgot to check it. :)